# Scala: instances of two different classes, same methods

Tags: generics, scala

This is a trivial question, I was just wondering if I can use something Scala-ish here. I have 2 different classes (`Server1` and `Server2`) both implement a common interface/trait (with methods `.A()` and `.B()`).

This obviously confuses the compiler:

```
var server = null
if(cond) server=new Server1 else server=new Server2
server.A() //or server.B()
```

I was mainly curious if I could use Scala's Option to get around this in a neat way. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type annotations can always be added:

```
var server: TraitOrInterface = null
```

However, since vars are somewhat icky...

```
val server = if (cond) {
   new Server1()
} else {
   new Server2()
}
```

In the second example, Scala should be able to unify types. (I am fairly certain there are some situations it can't unify -- or where it doesn't unify quite as desired, but give it a shot before falling back to type annotations, which can be added as per the first example.)

REPL demonstration:

```
class X
trait Y
class A extends X with Y {}
class B extends X with Y {}
val uni = if (true) new A() else new B()
uni
>> res3: X with Y = A@17b8cf0
```

Happy coding.

---

Structural typing example, the `type` alias is for convenience but technically not required.

```
class Cat { def speak() = "meow" }
class Dog { def speak() = "woof" }
type ThingThatSpeaks = { def speak(): String }

val speaker : ThingThatSpeaks = if (true /* smart */) new Cat() else new Dog()
speaker
>> res4: ThingThatSpeaks = Cat@2893fc
speaker.speak()
>> res5: String = meow
```

Note that the type annotation was required, otherwise...

```
val speaker = if (true /* smart */) new Cat() else new Dog()
speaker
>> res6: ScalaObject = Cat@f0ac6e
speaker.speak()
>> error: value speak is not a member of ScalaObject
```

Comment: what if it wasn't a common trait, but incidentally same method names? (yes, that's crap - but just in case)

Comment: @parsa Then you can use [structural typing](http://codemonkeyism.com/scala-goodness-structural-typing/) :-)

Comment: @parsa I added an example utilizing structural typing.

Answer (score 1):

Not `Option`, but `Either`:

```
var server = if (cond) Right(new Server1) else Left(new Server2)
server match {
    case Right(srv) => srv.A()
    case Left(srv) => srv.B()
}
```